# Do the questions "Is something something?" sound natural?

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language

For example, let's suppose we want to know what does Scrum Master (a role in a software development methodology called Scrum) do. Whether they are a manager (of a software project)? Or whether the Product Owner is a business analyst in Scrum.

- *Is Scrum Master a manager?*
- *Is a product manager a business requirements analyst in Scrum?*

Do such questions (*Is smth smth?*) sound natural, common? If not, than what is the most common, usual way to ask such questions in English?

Comment: It's **whether**.

Comment: You are on the right track.  All you are missing are couple of definite articles.  Is **the** Scrum Master a manager?  Is **the** product manager a business requirements analyst in **the** Scrum?